# Ramda: How to modify function parameters without `R.wrap`?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

How to override a methods parameter defaults, without wrap (since it's about to be removed). Consider the following.

```
let foo = (bar, { logToConsole = false }) => {
  if (logToConsole) console.log(bar);
  return bar;
};

// I want foo to always log, but I want to leave the option open to 
//   override that on a per instance basis (which excludes doing a 
//   `R.partial`). Looking at the methods available, `wrap` seems to 
//   do what I want...

foo = R.wrap(foo, (fn, bar, options) => {
  options = R.merge({ logToConsole: true }, options);
  return fn(bar, options);
}
```

So, reassigning foo, with the default flipped. Every time I call `foo` after, it will have the default changed.

Since `wrap` is deprecated, what should I be using instead?

I followed along [this thread](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1818), but didn't see how to solve this pattern with the examples there.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That discussion involved David showing that every use I would come up with for wrap could be rewritten more simply, especially with ES6 handy.

I'm not sure whether he's right, but it's not far off.  I've been using something like `wrap` for years, doing AOP-style work in JS, and I still do, just not using it inside Ramda.  Whether they all can be rewritten in a different manner, writing them all consistently is useful to me, but David's point was a good one.

Your case can, I believe, be rewritten pretty straightforwardly:

```
const foo2 = (bar, options) => foo(bar, R.merge({logToConsole: true}, options));

foo2(42);
// logs 42
//=> 42
foo2(99, {logToConsole: false});
// (doesn't log)
//=> 99
```

(I'm assuming that `command` in the original is supposed to be `bar`.  Is that correct?)

### Update

If you're looking to reassign `foo`, you can wrap that one up like this:

```
foo = ((orig) => 
  (bar, options) => orig(bar, R.merge({logToConsole: true}, options))
)(foo);
```

This would have the same behavior as `foo2` above.  (Obviously it won't work with your `const` declaration of `foo`.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! You're correct about `command`- I updated the question.

Comment: In this, and the other @davidchambers answer, the return of the "wrapping" method takes advantage of calling the original method. This makes it impossible to reassign the original method. You indicated that it would be less ideal to reassign the original method, but in my case I want to. The use case is that I only want to care about the logging logic, and possible override, in one place. I call the original method in the rest of the file regardless of what happened there. I suppose you will suggest that I just always assign it to a new variable regardless of modification.

Comment: @rjhilgefort: Updated to allow for reassignment... not that this is a technique I'd recommend.

Comment: Thanks for the update (I updated the question to not use `const`). I understand the warning of not overwriting. This is nice and clean, thanks again for taking the time to respond. Been really enjoying the shift to Ramda and FP in general.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different approach. I assume the options hash is always the last argument. If this is the case one can write a decorator:

```
function logLastArg(f) {
  return R.curryN(f.length, function() {
    console.log(R.last(arguments));
    return R.apply(f, arguments);
  });
}

function query(queryString, dbOpts) {
  return ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
}

var queryWithLogging = logLastArg(query);

query('SELECT username FROM users', {name: 'default'});
// => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

queryWithLogging('SELECT username FROM users', {name: 'default'});
// logs "{name: 'default'}"
// => ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: Note that the original was using the options object to determine *whether or not* to log.  What it actually logged was in this case the first parameter.  I would think that ideally this should be done without rewriting the original function, as that might be part of an external API.

Comment: @davidchambers. I'm not sure I see how this solutions does the same thing as what I accomplished with wrap above. Unless you were just showing that you could log any portion (as I could just console log something other than `R.last(arguments)` before calling the original method).

See also my concern from @ScottSauyet's answer.